# What does "that" in "that again" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Batman (2022), Bruce Wayne speaks to Alfred:

> Bruce Wayne: I never thought I'd feel fear like that again.
> I thought I'd mastered all that.I mean, I'm not afraid to die.
> I realize now there's something I haven't got past. This fear...of ever going
> through any of **that** again. Of losing somebody I care about.

What does "that" refer to?

Comment: He appears to be talking about some traumatic experience in his past. He fears having to go through a similar experience - 'any of that' - again.

Comment: 'That', pronoun, referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood. Some kind of scary incident? Like Batman's father and mother being killed? By Salvator Maroni, maybe (just a thought)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"that" refers to him losing someone he cared about, and he did not want to go through it *again* (did not want to lose someone he loved/cared *again*)